# php background process using exec function

Tags: php, exec, background-process

I have searched a lot to find the exact answer but didn't find any.

many people mentioned that we should **&** at end of command to don't wait for response.
for example to run **bg.php** in background , this was recommended:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php bg.php &");
```

but it doesn't work for me. and the main script waits for complete execution of the **bg.php**.

I also read somewhere to write **bg.php** output in a logfile but my background script doesn't produce any output. It does some process and then write something in database.

**I just want my script to run bg.php and don't wait for it to end.**

please help me including correct code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to reroute programs output somewhere too, usually /dev/null

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: works fine! but what is /dev/null directory? does this command write the output to a file?

Comment: /dev/null just discards the data sent to it, you can alternatively route it to some file if you need the program output

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using screen?  You can start up a screen session that runs in a detached process.

```
screen -d -m -S my_bg_session /usr/bin/php bg.php
```

Then you can connect to it later if it is still running:

```
screen -r my_bg_session
```