# PHP run multiple scripts simultaneously in background

Tags: php, shell, background-process

I want to run more than 300 PHP script simultaneously in background. I tried  using exec() one after another. But it runs sequentially. It means first it executes exec() first command then next exec() command. How can I run all PHP script in background at a time ? Current code :

```
exec("wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1");
exec("wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/index3.php >/dev/null 2>&1");
exec("wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/index4.php >/dev/null 2>&1");
exec("wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/index5.php >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

This script first executes index.php entirely and then executes index3,4,5. But I want to run all at a time. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Regards,
John

Comment: you are using the wget so it will execute one by one
you can use crontab command create a schedule job for all php file at one time where your current time would be now

Comment: Take a look at the `nohup` utility.

Comment: @bornprogrammer Any example would be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php background process using exec function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842767/php-background-process-using-exec-function)

Comment: See the question I've marked as a duplicate. Basically, you do it the same way you'd start off the process in the background directly from the command line -- add an extra ampersand to the end of the command (`wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &`). Though starting off 300 wgets at once may be a little heavy on the box; as Vivek suggests, you may want to look into task queueing systems that can give you control over the maximum number of simultaneous tasks, etc. Or maybe look into using something other than PHP -- plain shell might be better in this case...

Comment: @arkascha nohup is used to run in background not simultaneously... requirement is to run all php script simultaneously in background

Comment: @JohnMcLow i don't have any code example but can write the process
1) create a cronjob by using the command crontab -e in terminal and put all files using either curl extension or wget and execute it at same time

Comment: Put the list of urls you want in a file and run GNU Parallel like this `parallel -j 32 -k -a theFile 'wget -O - {} '` to do 32 in parallel at a time and keep outputs in order. Or echo the urls to GNU Parallel's stdin and omit the `-a theFile` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using php-rescue for the purpose. celery-php can also work for you.